# Can transitive relations in 3NF cause redundancies amongst other problems?

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization, 3nf

I know that redundancies can cause the user to inadvertently delete certain information, but that only applied, I believe, for 2NF. What about 3NF? I know there are transitive relations in 3NF too; however it is reciprocal between two determinants, so I believe the problem must be of a different nature. Also, is there any other issues with 3NF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're compliant to 3NF, you'll be covered for the vast majority of cases. Coming across one of the special cases covered under [Boyce-Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form), [4NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form) or [5NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form) is quite rare